# How do I create a time object from a formatted string, in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, time

I am aware of the class method datetime.strptime, but that produces a `datetime` object, not a `time` object. I was expecting there to be something analogous for `time` objects, that would accept a format string such as `"%H:%Mpm"` to convert strings like this:

```
txt = "21:22pm"
```

to an object like this:

```
datetime.time(21, 22)
```

Is this the best I can do?:

```
datetime.strptime("21:22pm", "%H:%Mpm").time()
```

Comment: What about [`time.strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime)?

Comment: Cool, I've only ever looked at the `datetime` module - however, it seems that the time module produces objects that are incompatible with the `datetime` module's `time` objects, e.g. it looks like I can't use datetime.combine with a time object from the time module.

Comment: Indeed. But, now your question is another. I recommend you start making yourself acquaintance with the documentation.

Comment: Short of using an `re` to match/extract the relevant parts and passing them directly to `datetime.time`.... None that I can think of. If you're doing combining, then do it at that stage...

Comment: I guess after you built everything on a datetime idea, it'd be pretty hard to bubble a time object in your code. [This](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) may give you more ideas. For example, how to get a datetime from a time object.